# Unable to select subitem from dropdown in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is an working example https://jsfiddle.net/79epsrmw/
But same in vs code not targeting to item1 sub menu, After passing unique id also.

```js
  
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        menuItems: [
        {
            name: 'Item 1',
          children: [{name: 'Subitem 1'},{name: 'Subitem 2'},{name: 'Subitem 3'}]
        },
        {
            name: 'Item 2'
        }
      ],
        selectedDropdown: 'None'
    },
    methods: {
        setSelectedItem(item) {
        this.selectedDropdown = item;
      }
    },
    ready: function() {
      $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      });    
    }
  })
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="app">
  <h2>Vue.js multi-level dropdown example</h2>
  <p>
  Selected element: {{ selectedDropdown }}
  </p>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li v-for="item in menuItems" v-bind:class="{'dropdown-submenu': item.children}">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">{{item.name}}<span class="caret" v-if="item.children"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" v-if="item.children">
          <li v-for="child in item.children"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" @click="setSelectedItem(child.name)">{{child.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting an error ""Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.eslint-plugin-vue
So in order to clear the error i have taken  key and passed unique id to it

{{child.name}}

So in order to clear the error i have taken  key and passed unique id to it. like :key="child"

Issue is in editor it is working fine, But in vs code after passing unique id, I am unable to select the sub menu in item1.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/negqvmjd/35/

```js
  
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function () {
    return {
        menuItems: [
        {
            name: 'Item 1',
          children: [{name: 'Subitem 1'},{name: 'Subitem 2'},{name: 'Subitem 3'}]
        },
        {
          name: 'Item 2',
                    children: []
        }
      ],
        selectedDropdown: 'None'
            }
    },
    methods: {
        setSelectedItem(item,childLength, bool) {
                if(childLength === 0 && bool === false){
    this.selectedDropdown = item;
}
else if(childLength !==0 && bool === true){
    this.selectedDropdown = item;
}
        
      }
    },
    ready: function() {
      $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      });    
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="app">
  <h2>Vue.js multi-level dropdown example</h2>
  <p>
  Selected element: {{ selectedDropdown }}
  </p>
  
   
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li v-for="item in menuItems" v-bind:class="{'dropdown-submenu': item.children.length}">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#" @click=setSelectedItem(item.name,item.children.length,false)>{{item.name}}<span class="caret" v-if="item.children.length"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" v-if="item.children.length">
          <li v-for="child in item.children"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" @click="setSelectedItem(child.name,item.children.length,true)">{{child.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```